# How to switch local video without switching audio in a webrtc conference?

Tags: camera, webrtc

I have two or more cameras connected to my pc. My goal is, to switch between the local cameras in an ongoing webrtc videoconference - but only to switch video from camera 1 to camera 2 NOT audio. Audio should always come from camera 1.

How to toggle between the two videoTracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440724/webrtc-change-device-camera-in-realtime).

Basically you can use replaceTrack() in Firefox to do this today for a seamless replacement of a camera.  This is being added to the spec, but Chrome doesn't support it yet.

The best you can do in Chrome today is to get a new stream with the same mic but a different camera, remove the old stream/tracks from the PeerConnection and add the new one, and then handle onnegotiationneeded and renegotiate.  This will likely cause a glitch, and will require at least a couple of round-trip-times to complete.  (This will work in Firefox as well.